# Ensure strict comparability at compile time in Go 1.20?

Tags: go, generics, comparable, compile-time-type-checking

In Go 1.18 and Go 1.19 I can ensure at compile time that a type is **strictly comparable**, i.e. it supports `==` and `!=` operators and those are guaranteed to **not panic at run time**.

This is useful for example to avoid inadvertently adding fields to a struct that could cause unwanted panics.

I just attempt to instantiate `comparable` with it:

```golang
// supports == and != but comparison could panic at run time
type Foo struct {
    SomeField any
}

func ensureComparable[T comparable]() {
    // no-op
}

var _ = ensureComparable[Foo] // doesn't compile because Foo comparison may panic
```

This is possible in Go 1.18 and 1.19 due to the very definition of the `comparable` constraint:

> The predeclared interface type comparable denotes the set of all non-interface types that are comparable

Even though the Go 1.18 and 1.19 spec fail to mention types that are not interfaces but also not strictly comparable, e.g. `[2]fmt.Stringer` or `struct { foo any }`, the gc compiler does reject these as arguments for `comparable`.

Playground with several examples: https://go.dev/play/p/_Ggfdnn6OzZ

With Go 1.20, instantiating `comparable` will be aligned with the [broader notion of comparability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators). This makes `ensureComparable[Foo]` compile **even though I don't want it to**.

Is there a way to statically ensure strict comparability with Go 1.20?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test that `Foo` is strictly comparable in Go 1.20, instantiate `ensureComparable` **with a type parameter** constrained by `Foo`.

```golang
// unchanged
type Foo struct {
    SomeField any
}

// unchanged
func ensureComparable[T comparable]() {}

// T constrained by Foo, instantiate ensureComparable with T
func ensureStrictlyComparable[T Foo]() {
    _ = ensureComparable[T] // <---- doesn't compile
}
```

<sub>This solution has been originally [suggested by Robert Griesemer here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56548#issuecomment-1317673963).</sub>

---

So how does it work?

Go 1.20 introduces a difference between **implementing** an interface and [**satisfying** a constraint](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Satisfying_a_type_constraint):

> A type `T` satisfies a constraint `C` if
>
> - `T` implements `C`; or
> - `C` can be written in the form `interface{ comparable; E }`, where `E` is a basic interface and `T` is comparable and implements
>   `E`.

The second bullet point is the exception that permits interfaces, and types with interfaces, to instantiate `comparable`.

So now in Go 1.20 the type `Foo` itself can instantiate `comparable` due to the satisfiability exception. But the type parameter `T` isn't `Foo`. Comparability of type parameters is defined [differently](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Type parameters are comparable if they are strictly comparable (see below).
>
> [...]
>
> Type parameters are strictly comparable if all types in their type set are strictly comparable.

The type set of `T` includes a type `Foo` that is not strictly comparable (because it has an interface field), therefore `T` doesn't satisfy `comparable`. Even though `Foo` itself does.

This trick effectively makes the program fail to compile if `Foo`'s operators `==` and `!=` might panic at run time.

Comment: Let's say I have an API that requires strictly comparable types. Is there a way to abstract the static check? Or, does each caller need to implement this check for their respective `Foo` type(s)?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco In `ensureStrictlyComparable` you can probably constrain `T` to a union of the types whose strict comparability must hold, because the 1.20 spec says *"... all types in their type set are strictly comparable"*, so if just one isn't, compilation still fails

Comment: @HymnsForDisco on a second thought: if your question is from the PoV of a library writer, then *you the library writer* cannot statically make sure your third-party callers will always use strictly comparable type. Mainly because 1) you can't possibly know what types they will define, and 2) the only general-purpose constraint you have at your disposal is still `comparable`, and callers will indeed be able to instantiate it with non-strictly comparable types.